# can't refactor package name - java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, refactoring, rename

I am working on a project that uses `android-support-v4.jar` as a library (in the `libs` folder of my app), and I want to rename the `android.support.v4` package in it but I am told that this can't be done because the directory is not located in the project.

(But I need it because I have ActionSherlock as an imported module, which also uses android-support-v4 as a dependency. When I first ran the app, I get error message, related to the loading of this library twice)

Answer (score 1):

You should have the same copy of the `android-support-V4.jar` in both `libs` directories. Just copy the one on your `libs` into the `ActionBarSherlock` `libs` directory.

Comment: that's what I did : I get now this message `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;`

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using `intelliJ idea`

Comment: sorry I am not familiar with IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

You can't refactor other people's package structure. And: You don't need to.

Just remove the library from your own project's `libs` folder.
The IDE is smart enough to take the support-library from ActionBarSherlock. (if you have imported it correctly)

Answer (score 0):

In ActionSherlock module in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

and in your main project in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries: ActionSherlockModule')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely one of the following:

1. You are referencing two different versions of `android-support-v4.jar`. Check the file signature to ensure that both projects are using the same file.
2. You have included the sources of the support library in the parent project and are attempting to provide a jar in the child project. It's recommended to simply use provided `android-support-v4.jar` from the SDK folder.

In other words: no, you should not be attempting to rename the package name of the support library.

Comment: Yes indeed I have two different versions of the same `android-support-v4.jar` but when I delete the one in the `libs` folder, `imports` in  my main activity is no longer recognized. And when I delete the one in the `ActionBarSherlock`, this one is not compiled anymore. How can I circumvent the problem

Comment: You need the library in both projects; simply ensure that the files are identical.

Comment: sorry I am very new to `Android`, how can I detect if their identical ?

Comment: I copied the support file from the app libs directory the one of `ActionBarSherlock` and I get this message : `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;`

Comment: This likely means that the library occurs twice in the class path. See [the answers in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387530/android-dex-unexpected-top-level-exception-already-added), especially the one relating to nested dependencies.